# Filtering data - KStream or KTable?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have data of a table in Avro Schema on a Kafka Topic. Now I want to filter that data according to a value of a specific column. So which one should I use?

Comment: Do you want to filter them and re-store in kafka?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `KTable` for this operation. [`filter()` is a stateless operation on a `KStream`](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#filter(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate)).